# .NET Driver with LINQ: NotSupportedException: $project or $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

The following query works:

```
return Database
    .GetCollection<MyEntity>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.StartDate <= instance && x.EndDate >= instance)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Guid)
    .Select(x => x.First().Id)
    .ToList();
```

But, when adding an $in condition (see below), the following exception is thrown:

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.NotSupportedException: $project or $group does not support
>   First({document}{_id})

```
return Database
    .GetCollection<MyEntity>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => guidKeys.Contains(x.Key.Guid)) // $in condition
    .Where(x => x.StartDate <= instance && x.EndDate >= instance)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Guid)
    .Select(x => x.First().Id)
    .ToList();
```

I understand that a lot of LINQ is not yet supported by the driver, but I can't understand how introducing that addition match stage (using $in) could result in an incompatibility for the grouping stage.

Is anyone able to explain why this is happening?

I am using MongoDB 3.2 with the .NET Driver 2.2.2.

#### EDIT:

`MyEntity` looks something like this:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MyEntity: BaseMongoDocument
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Binary)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("startDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("endDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("key")]
    public SquidDocument Key { get; set; }

    [BsonConstructor]
    private MyEntity()
    { }
}

public class SquidDocument
{
    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("squid")]
    public string Squid { get; private set; }

    [BsonConstructor]
    private SquidDocument(Guid guid, string squid)
    {
        Guid = realSquid.Guid;
        Squid = realSquid.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: As error suggest and you mentioned above, LINQ is not fully implemented of by MongoDB driver so does $in operator.

Comment: $in certainly is supported.  And I the grouping is working on the first query.

Comment: hmm, I don't see $in in first query.

Comment: That's the point.  The first query (without $in) works fine.  The second query (exact same as the first, but with an $in condition) fails with that NotSupportedException on the grouping.

Comment: What does MyEntity look like (any any referenced classes)?

Comment: @CraigWilson: Question amended

Comment: You should probably file a bug at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project. I'll bet it has something to do with the naming of "Key". You could try to use a name other than "Key" and see if that fixes it for now.

Comment: @CraigWilson: I have filed the issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1671